# Finding the simple formula for like vs dislike ratio percentage

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I have a like button and a dislike button. I want to quickly display in a percentage format how much people like it, -100% being everyone dislikes and 100% being everyone likes.

What would be the math forumula to find this percentage.

Say 100 people like it and 50 people hate it.

Would it be something like

100 + 50 / 2 ?

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: How about #likes/total ?  So your case would be $\frac {100}{150}=66.66\dots \%$

Comment: @lulu:  that gives $0$ when everyone dislikes, not $-100\%$

Comment: @RossMillikan  Ah, true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $$\frac {likes-dislikes}{likes+dislikes}$$

Comment: In other words, the average value of a vote, where a like is worth $1$ and a dislike is worth $-1$.